# How to return a polygon geometry from overlapping rows that share a same value in another column

Tags: postgis, postgresql

This one is not very easy to explain but basically I have a table with postcodes and a table with area boundaries.

These boundaries have an area_id and postcodes that match the postcode table

This area_id repeats itself for each postcode that the boundary contains, so the geometries should overlap at times, for example:

Area| postcode

A | NW1

A | NW2

A | NW3

B | NW2

B | SE4

Illustrated, something that would look like the below, with the middle polygon overlapping since it belongs to both area A and B:

[image]

Query used so far and doesn't work is

```
create table test as
select area_id, st_union(b.geom) as geom 
from postcodes b, area_boundary c 
where b.postcode = c.pcd 
group by c.area_id
```

Comment: Could you explain how it does not work? From the query it would seem that you want to merge all the postcodes geometries together that share a common area_id

Comment: it ignores overlapping geometries

Comment: ok, I think the problem is that you are trying to merge every geometry that is an A and everyone that is a B, etc, which is what the GROUP BY in conjunction with ST_Union does. However, this isn't working because you are joining on WHERE b.postcode = c.pcd, and, based on your example rows, none of the postcodes in group A are the same, and likewise group B. It is possible I have misunderstood the question.

Comment: so, in your picture there are three polygons (represented by their boundaries, i.e. as (multi)linestrings?). the middle one represents an area of two different postcodes. does your *area_boundary.pcd* column of that area contain both these postcodes? and if so, how (e.g. as an array)? your goal then is to merge this area's geometry with each of the other two, effectively duplicate the area for each postcode and merge it with the respective other boundary?

Comment: The middle is one post code that is part of area A and area B. Too late but I solved this problem by creating an intermediate table with the union